# Change the subject when using django-templated-email

Tags: django, email, django-templates

To send email with an HTML tag, I use [django-templated-email](https://github.com/bradwhittington/django-templated-email). How can I change the subject?

```
send_templated_mail(
    template_name='druduser/views/register_email',
    from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
    recipient_list=[email],
    context={'username': username,},
)
```

---

I found the solution:

I have to put `{% block subject %}` block out of `{% block html %}` ...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: As per the link you provided in documentation it says -For legacy purposes you can specify email subjects in your settings file (but, the preferred method is to use a {% block subject %} in your template):

TEMPLATED_EMAIL_DJANGO_SUBJECTS = {
    'welcome':'Welcome to my website',
}

Comment: In `context`, try this: `context={'username': username, 'subject': 'My new subject'}`

Answer (score 2):

Quote from docs:

> For legacy purposes you can specify email subjects in your settings
>   file (but, the preferred method is to use a {% block subject %} in
>   your template)

So, you can specify a custom subject right in your template by defining a `subject` block: see [docs](https://github.com/bradwhittington/django-templated-email#your-template).

---

If you want to go with `TEMPLATED_EMAIL_DJANGO_SUBJECTS` setting, `template_name` should be just a name of the actual template (without extension).

Define `TEMPLATED_EMAIL_DJANGO_SUBJECTS` dictionary in `settings.py`, e.g.:

```
TEMPLATED_EMAIL_DJANGO_SUBJECTS = {
    'welcome':'Welcome to my website',
}
```

Define where to get templates and a file extension:

```
TEMPLATED_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_DIR = 'templated_email/' #Use '' for top level template dir
TEMPLATED_EMAIL_FILE_EXTENSION = 'email'
```

Then just send the mail using `welcome` as a `template_name`:

```
send_templated_mail(
    template_name='welcome',
    from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
    recipient_list=[email],
    context={'username': username,},
    )
```

In this case your template should be in `templated_email/welcome.email`.

Hope that helps.